# How to Use Setter of Custom SwiftUI Binding after Value Conversion

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a custom SwiftUI binding where I convert a value before it's rendered in a TextField in my view. I do this because I want to convert the number of minutes (stored as an `Int` in my database) to one of two time formats (HHMM or #.#).

`app.flight` is a `@Published` variable on an `ObservableObject` in my view model. `duration` is the `Int` property of my object, and `timeForm` is an extension that does the time conversion and returns the appropriate `String` value.

Here's my binding:

```
let time = Binding(
  get: {
    app.flight.duration.timeForm //Converts the Int to a String
  },
  set: { $0 } <-- ???
)
```

...and here is my `TextField` in my view where I use the `time` binding:

```
TextField(timeDisplayHHMM ? "####" : "#.#", text: time, onCommit:{
  print(time.wrappedValue) //<-- Prints the initial value from the binding's getter
})
```

I need the setter to finish setting the value of `time` so that when I access it in my `onCommit`, it has the latest value the user has entered. But as I have it, it's printing the original value from the binding's getter.

How do I make the `set` statement in my binding pass on the set value so it's ready by the time I use it in `onCommit`?

Comment: Looks to me like you need to parse the user-entered string, convert to the appropriate Int value and save it to app.flight.duration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timeDisplayHHMM = true
    @State var time = ""
    @State var app_flight_duration: Int = 0  // <-- for testing

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("time: " + time)
            Text("duration: \(app_flight_duration)")

            TextField(timeDisplayHHMM ? "####" : "#.#",
                      text: Binding(
                        get: { time },
                        set: {
                            time = $0
                            // here convert to int,
                            // you need to do a lot more than this simple example
                            if let theInt = Int($0) {
                                app_flight_duration = theInt // assign to your model
                            }
                        }
                      ),
                      onCommit:{
                print("-----> time " + time + "  app_flight_duration: \(app_flight_duration)")
            })
        }
    }
    
}
```